# meteor app not working on modulus

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

keep in mind, i have this app running perfectly locally on a few boxes shared locally and online.

i have uploaded my meteor app to modulus. the templating works fine, and the database has migrated fine... but none of my templates get populated. using the (js chrome) console i can access all of my models MyModel.find({foo:bar}) i can get records, but my render scripts fail.

most of my 'pages' are rendered on initial app load, all rendered in divs off screen so i can transition the few pages on and off screen, and then filled reactively and moved on screen. static content in these divs loads, and dynamic content loads if called directly from the router. any ideas would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Meteor in production mode locally? I had a similar problem at one point and found that the difference between production and development mode was the issue(minification etc) and not the specific host.

To test your app in production mode on your local machine just run meteor with the production option set

```
meteor --production
```

Another idea is that there is possibly an issue with the node version. If you are using the Modulus CLI to deploy, it is currently using an older version of Demeteorizer which sets a node version of v0.10.22 while the current release of Meteor is dependent on Node v0.10.25 or greater. I have contacted Modulus and they told me they will update this sometime soon, but I have no idea what kind of timeframe they work on. For what its worth I am running a pretty complex Meteor 0.8.0.1 app on Modulus with multiple package and NPM dependencies and I have not run into any issues with running on the earlier version of Node.

If you do think this could be the issue I'm told the Modulus CLI has a -n option which you can use to manually set the node version. Something like this:

```
modulus deploy -n 0.10.25
```

Comment: thanks - just tried the --production switch locally and all still works fine. just been through adding console logs to all of my functions to try and track down the issue - it seems that the DB is loading (as i can query it in the console) but any call that i make to it on first page load fails.

i'm calling my scripts using Template.contents.rendered = function(){..};

i'm really not sure why my app can't initially query the models that i know are there!

Comment: this is driving me insane! if i paste the render function into the console on the modulus hosted site - it does as expected! but still wont find my models on initial load!